# Performance diagnostics of an ASP .NET MVC 5 website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP .NET MVC 5 website which runs perfectly on my local machine, but after publishing it to a hosting provider response time from the server is always about 30 seconds (on localhost it is about 100-500ms depending on a page). And I am not talking about first response after some timeout, I am talking about every response, even to pages like "Hello world" with a very simple ViewModel and maybe a couple of strings in ViewBag. At the same time, the static content (like .css and .js files) are returned quickly. I have performed several optimizations, such as:

1. Installed Razor Generator and compiled all .cshtml files
2. Got rid of dynamic variables and ViewBags
3. Made sure that I'm using "release" configuration
4. Unfortunately, my hosting provider doesn't allow me to configure IIS Application pool, so I couldn't optimize Idle Timeout etc.

Sometimes (very rarely) response time becomes normal (about 200-500ms) but this is for a very short period of time. I've tried several hosting providers and the issue is still there, so it seems to me that there are performance problems with my website but unfortunately I cannot locate and fix them. I'm using shared hosting, by the way, not VDS. So, the question is: Are there any standard diagnostic procedures intended locate and fix performance problems with ASP .NET MVC websites?

Comment: sounds more like a host issue to me

Comment: Agree with @TJWolschon , sounds like your webhost has overtaxed their webserver.

Comment: If you use one of the MVC templates that VS comes with out of the box, and deploy those, how long do _they_ take to download a page (generally)?

Comment: @TJWolschon I also thought so, but hotst's technical support told me that they don't have any problems on their side. And I also tried two more hosting providers and the problems weren't gone. I'm thinkig of using VDS instead of shared hosting, maybe this will help me resolve the issue

Comment: @AntonVoronin try mjwills' suggestion, see if that is any different. If that doesn't work. We're going to need to see some code.

Comment: @mjwills Hm, haven't tried that, I'll give it a try.

Comment: "I also thought so, but hotst's technical support told me that they don't have any problems on their side." If it affects simple pages like Hello World, that is a pretty strong case something is wrong on their side. Basically you have "way to slow response time on page X". This is a specific problem with reproduceable behavior they can go and debug/fix. The 30 seconds part does smell like a timeout, but maybe a odder one? What if a cache is trying to get a fresh copy, times out after 30 seconds, then just delivers the last version?

Comment: Also a pet-peeve of mine is proper Exception handling. Inproper handling could easily cause issues like this without any debug information. Here are two articles I link a lot and I think cover all the basic do & dont cases. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: You can also try creating a Free Azure subscription (30-day trial, in case if you haven't yet), and try hosting your application there (as a web app) and see how it performs there. Even in shared hosting (i.e., Free mode), Azure apps should perform fairly better. This may give you direction of further investigation.

Comment: Shared hosting is doomed to be slow. Otherwise, how come the hosting entities create dedicated offering? If you cannot accept slowness, switch to other options (more expensive obviously). You cannot get both fast and cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several times of trying to find out solution for the issue with bad performance, I tried to deploy one of Visual Studio's included MVC projects (like @mjwills advised) and it didn't have any performance issues so I was pretty sure that there were problems with my project, not hosting provider. So, the solution for me was to create a new project from scratch and move all code from previous one to the new project, also deleting all the junk code and unnecessary nuget packages. I think that problems were caused either by bad entity framework configuration or by problems with nuget packages installed.